# How to select one column values with all values occurences in second column

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let's assume we have a table

```
values
    (a, 2),
    (b, 1),
    (b, 2),
    (c, 1),
    (c, 3),
    (d, 4)
```

I want to get values from column1 that has pairs with specific values in column2.
E.g. values 1 and 2. As we can see in column2 there is 1 or 2 in rows (a, 2), (b, 1), (b, 2) and (c, 1) but we need to have both occurences so needed column1 value is b. How do I need to make query for doing this if values that I need occurence with given as array?

I have no problem for at least one occurence, but can't figure out how to do this.

```
SELECT column1 from table
where column2 = any(array[1, 2])
```

I don't understand why I'm stuck on this

UPD:
Because the table I'm working with has not only two cols, but few others that gives row uniqueness. It is possible that this pair of values will be duplicated.
Like this:

```
values
    (a, 2, unique_value),
    (b, 1, unique_value),
    (b, 2, unique_value),
    (c, 1, unique_value),
    (c, 3, unique_value),
    (d, 4, unique_value),
    (c, 1, unique_value)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregation and a `having` clause:

```
select col1
from t
where col2 in (1, 2)
group by col1
having count(*) = 2;
```

If the values can be duplicated, use:

```
having count(distinct col2) = 2
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that this pair of values can be duplicated. In table I'm working with there are some other attributes than these that gives rows thier uniqueness.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT ...)` in the `HAVING` clause:

```
WITH data(fst, snd) AS (
    VALUES ('a', 2),
           ('b', 1),
           ('b', 2),
           ('c', 1),
           ('c', 3),
           ('d', 4),
           ('b', 2) -- added this
)
SELECT fst
FROM data
WHERE snd IN (1, 2)
GROUP BY fst
-- you could also use
-- HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT snd) = 2
HAVING ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT snd ORDER BY snd) = ARRAY[1, 2]
```

returns

```
+---+
|fst|
+---+
|b  |
+---+
```

Comment: Looks better that I did. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using Gordon Linoff answer I made this query

```
select column1 from (
    select column1 from table
    where column2 = any(array[1, 2])
    group by column1, column2
) q
 group by column1
 having count(*) = 2
```